# How to stop recursive function after specific times of repetitions?

Tags: python, function, recursion

Is there any way to stop recursive function after two times of repetitions?I've tried counter variable which it seems going nowhere!

```
def recursive_divder_prime_number (numbers):
    counter = 0
    for num in numbers:
        print(num,'we are talking about')
        if num ==1:
            dividers [num] = 1
        elif num >1:
            print ('Hi')
            a = [i for i in range(2,num) if num%i ==0]
            print (a)
            if len(a) == 0:
                print(num, ' is a prim number')
            recursive_divder_prime_number(a)
            counter += 1
            
recursive_divder_prime_number ([8,1000,669,1])
```

Comment: By *two times of repetitions*, you mean after calling the function two times?

Comment: The counter value is increased in elif only, but there is no break condition of the loop.

Comment: What is this trying to do? What/Where is *dividers*?

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? What is `dividers` and why only `dividers[1]` is set? Why do you want to stop recursing after 2 times -- what does that have to do with primes? What is the expected output for the given example list?

Answer (score 0):

Increment counter at each recursive iteration. Return when counter reaches 2.

```
def recursive_divder_prime_number(numbers, counter=0):
    for num in numbers:
        print(num, 'we are talking about')
        if num == 1:
            dividers[num] = 1
        elif num > 1:
            print('Hi')
            a = [i for i in range(2, num) if num % i == 0]
            print(a)
            if len(a) == 0:
                print(num, ' is a prime number')
            if counter < 2:  # Stop after two repetitions
                recursive_divder_prime_number(a, counter + 1)

recursive_divder_prime_number([8, 1000, 669, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing you have mentioned the `counter` variable and have initialized it with 0 but you've not used it anywhere.

As per the code logic that you have written, counter variable value will be increased by 1 for each `num` = 8 and `num` = 1000 and after that the recursive function should not be executed.

Find the modified code below:

```
def recursive_divder_prime_number (numbers):
    counter = 0
    for num in numbers:
        print(num,'we are talking about')
        if num ==1:
            dividers [num] = 1
        elif num >1 and counter < 2: # get inside the else block and execute the recursive call only when counter < 2
            print ('Hi')
            a = [i for i in range(2,num) if num%i ==0]
            print (a)
            if len(a) == 0:
                print(num, ' is a prim number')
            recursive_divder_prime_number(a)
            counter += 1
            
recursive_divder_prime_number ([8,1000,669,1])
```

Thank you.